# Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined ---- how to remove the error please

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-objects, swiper.js

I am doing `swiperjs` first time, but there's error occurs: `main.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined`

Some resource load requests were throttled while the tab was in background, and no request was sent from the queue in the last 1 minute. This means previously requested in-flight requests haven't received any response from servers.

I really have no idea how to fix this, please help me what to do if any possible solutions I would try. thank you so much.

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
var swiperProjects = new Swiper(".projects__container", {
   loop: true,
   spaceBetween:24,

    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
    },
    breakpoints: {
          1200: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: -56,
      
     
          },
        },
  });
```

Comment: Is your main.js defined before the swiper js file?

Comment: Seems to be working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-zbuu2s?file=index.html). As @epascarello said, make sure that your `main.js` is imported after the `swiper-bundle.min.js` script tag or make use of [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer).

Comment: thanks @vighnesh153 and @ eoascarello it worked